# Given a DataFrame of datetimes, plot yearly user access

Tags: python, pandas

Given the DataFrame below, plot user access by year.

Preferable a line graph with x-axis being years and y-axis being number of times accessed in that year.

DataFrame:

```
In:
    print df
Out:
    0     2016-10-01
    1     2015-11-05
    2     2017-12-07
    3     2016-08-09
    4     2015-11-22
    5     2016-12-13
    6     2017-03-25
    7     2016-09-11
    8     2017-04-12
    9     2016-08-29
    10    2015-11-04
    Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Imported Modules: matplotlib, pandas, and seaborn:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['date'].dt.year.value_counts().sort_index().plot.bar()
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['date'].dt.year.value_counts().sort_index())
2015    3
2016    5
2017    3
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

**Explanation**:

1. First convert values to years by [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html)
2. Count by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html) because default sorting in `value_counts` by top values
3. Last plot by [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html)

[image: graph]

Comment: That works like a charm. And `df['date'].dt.year.value_counts().sort_index().plot()` will give me the life graph that I needed.